# How to use fsyncLock() and fsyncUnlock() in pymongo for locking the write operation for concurrency

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to deduct the amount from my collection concurrently so I need to maintain the amount consistent.

**Example:**

```
My balance -> 1000
User 1 -> trying to deduct 700
User 2 -> trying to deduct 800  (Both users are accessing same account using different device)
```

they try to debit the amount at the same time . So I need concurrency

In mongoDB we can use fsyncLock() and fsyncUnlock()  but I need to use this feature in pymongo (Python) module. How can I achieve this feature?

Comment: Use [transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) for concurrency instead of fsynclock. Don't use fsynclock in day to day operations since it literally locks the whole server so no one else can use it until you unlock it.

Comment: Sir, I have read the concept of fsyncLock and now I am clear about it use. But sir I didn't find the solution to achieve the above mentioned problem, that how to implement in python for concurrency while updating the. Sir please suggest me about that. You have suggested me to use transactions for concurrency but I am not able to understand this (I am a beginner). So please elaborate more.

Comment: There are some examples with multiple languages in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/ and there are some example code using Python in https://github.com/jdrumgoole/pymongo-transactions. If your code doesn't work, please post the code you tried and the error message you see.

Comment: If you are new to MongoDB, I suggest you invest some time in [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com) to learn more about the concepts and syntax.

Comment: Okay sir, First I will learn and than I will connect with you later on. Thanks for guideline

Answer (score 0):

db.fsyncLock() and db.fsyncUnlock() are mongo shell methods not available from pymongo. Instead, you can call to the fsync administrative command to perform the same operation against the admin database. Something like:

```
import pymongo
db_host='__put_your_ip_or_hostname_here__'
client = pymongo.MongoClient(db_host)
db = client['admin']
db.command("fsync", lock=True)
```

But, as [kevinadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619724/kevinadi) said in the comments, Use transactions for concurrency instead of fsynclock. This command is intended to be used to perform filesystem-level backups when the data and journal folders lives separate volumes/filesystems.