# how to lock pymongo collection to reading & writing?

Tags: python, mongodb, locking, pymongo

I have a mongo instance running on docker container:

```
docker run \
-d \
--name mongo \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=bla \
-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=bla \
-p 27017:27017 \
mongo
```

and I have a process that uses mongo in the following manner:

```
def init():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://bla:bla@localhost:27017')
    db = client['db']
    collection = db['col']
    collection.insert_one({'ok': False})
    return collection


def critical_section(collection):
    if list(collection.find({'ok': False})):
        # do stuff
        collection.update_one({'ok': False}, {'ok': True})


collection = init()
critical_section(collection)
```

I have a number of concurrent processes running the `critical_section` function, so I want to lock the collection before the critical section, and unlock it afterwards (if I don't do that, 2 processes can `find` a document, however, the first will manage to update, and the second will fail...)

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64158677/3512538) to lock the db:

```
collection = init()
pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://bla:bla@localhost:27017')['admin'].command('fsync', lock=True)
critical_section(collection)
pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://bla:bla@localhost:27017')['admin'].command('fsyncUnlock')
```

however, this only locks write operations, which doesn't cut it for me.

1. How can I lock for reading as well?
2. Can I lock the collection, instead of the entire DB?
3. I now think I can just skip the find, and do a `if collection.update_one().updated_count == 1: # do stuff...`, though I'm not sure it solves exactly what I need, because without the `find`, I can't know the id of the item I updated

Answer (score 0):

See [MongoDB concurrent update to same document is not behaving atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65915366/mongodb-concurrent-update-to-same-document-is-not-behaving-atomic/65915837#65915837) for an example implementation.

> Can I lock the collection, instead of the entire DB?

Trying to solve concurrency issues with locking (i.e. making it so that the database is unusable by more than one client) is suboptimal in that it doesn't scale, hence isn't useful for cases when you *actually* have concurrency.

This is why conditional updates, MVCC/snapshot read concern and similar constructs provide *atomicity* and *consistency* but not *locking*.

Comment: I actually wrapped the update function with a wrapper that, given modified count != 1 raises an exception. I changed it and now I think I got it to work